# Incomplete implemention - @implementation View Controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, ios6, iphone-5

I am having some trouble with coding an app, when I try and run, it errors coming up with incomplete implementation.

Here is the code for the ViewController.m - could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I will also include the code for ViewController.h below the code for .m

#### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

 -(IBAction)infoButtonpressed:(id)sender;
 {
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];

}

-(IBAction)sound1 {

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;

soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound1", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);

UInt32 soundID;

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}

-(IBAction)sound2 {

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;

soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound2", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);

UInt32 soundID;

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}

-(IBAction)sound3 {

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;

soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound3", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);

UInt32 soundID;

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}

-(IBAction)sound4 {

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;

soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound4", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);

UInt32 soundID;

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}

-(IBAction)sound5 {

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;

soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound5", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);

UInt32 soundID;

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}

-(IBAction)sound6 {

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;

soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound6", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);

UInt32 soundID;

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}

@end
```

#### ViewController.h

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController :UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)switchviews;

-(IBAction)sound1;

-(IBAction)sound2;

-(IBAction)sound3;

-(IBAction)sound4;

-(IBAction)sound5;

-(IBAction)sound6;

-(IBAction)infoButtonpressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(IBAction)switchviews;
```

is declared in your header file but is never implemented in the implementation (`.m`) file.

Answer (score 0):

@H2CO3 - is right

in your application `-(IBAction)switchviews;` is declare in `.h` file but it is not declare in `.m` file. so first you need to declare -(IBAction)switchviews; method in `.m` file with related code.